# regex extract string word

Tags: javascript, regex

**how can you extract field- * but other than field-req**

input:

```
form-field field-input field-req
form-field field-parents field-req
cell-header form-field field-input
form-field field-responsible field-req
form-field field-select cdsddsadsa
form-field field-select field-req
form-field field-textarea field-req
form-field field-textarea
```

output:

```
field-input
field-parents
field-input
field-responsible
field-select
field-select
field-textarea
field-textarea
```

**I have this, but it does not meet**

```
\bfield\-((?!.*req).*)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/9y7pAV/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/\bfield-(?!req\b)\w+/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9y7pAV/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `field-` - a literal substring
- `(?!req\b)` - the must not be `req` and end of word boundary immediately to the right of the current location
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (replace with `[a-zA-Z]+` to only match ASCII letters).